# Dynamics CRM 2011 Creating Custom Reports

Tags: xml, crm, bids, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to create some custom reports using BIDS. My proof of concept is using the quote entity.

I have created a sub-report using the following FetchXML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="quotedetail">
<attribute name="productid" />
<attribute name="productdescription" />
<attribute name="priceperunit" />
<attribute name="quantity" />
<attribute name="extendedamount" />
<attribute name="quotedetailid" />
<attribute name="isproductoverridden" />
<order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
<link-entity name="quote" from="quoteid" to="quoteid" alias="aa">
<filter type="and">
<condition attribute="quotenumber" operator="eq" value="@quoteid" />
</filter>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

This worked when the quoteid parameter was supplied at runtime.
I then created the main report with the following FetchXML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="quote" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote">
<attribute name="name" />
<attribute name="totalamount" />
<attribute name="quoteid" />
<order attribute="name" descending="false" />
</entity>
</fetch>
```

I get the prompt for quote id, which when I enter I get the following error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>   An error has occurred during report processing.
>   Cannnot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1.
>   The XML passed to the platform is not well-formed XML.
>   Invalid XML.

I have read numerous blogs and articles and tried lots of variations with filters and prefilters but I can get no further. Hopefully someone can see my error and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sub-report - try changing this line:

```
<condition attribute="quotenumber" operator="eq" value="@quoteid" />
```

to:

```
<condition attribute="quoteid" operator="eq" value="@quoteid" />
```

It was looking for the quote number rather than the unique quote identifier as the key value.